# How to increase video views count in java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, video, youtube

I have a Video based project where all uploaded video store in 3rd party video cloud and we increase the video views count when click play icon and log in mongodb .so if user click on 100 video then we hit db 100 times.

My Problem

1. Can we reduce hit on db.
2. How youtube increase video views count.
3. when i play any video and refresh the page video views count not increase on
       youtube.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to understand is, video counts are increased based on unique IP address/session requests (Ideally). So, if you continuously hit video from same browser and IP address, it will not increase counts.

```
1.  Can we reduce hit on db.?
```

You can track the video counts increment in memory using some list or so. When session gets closed, you can add this counts in DB. BUT this is not recommended, as in between if something goes wrong, you will miss all the hits to your videos. Better you can optimize the code in such a way that, even if you want to make entry each time you get hit on your video, system should run smoothly.

```
2. How youtube increase video views count.? / 3. when i play any video and refresh the page video views not increase on youtube.?
```

We really can't predict how they are going to increase the count but, most probable way should be the same as I discussed in first para. So refreshing page will never increase video count.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Ved for Your prompt response.
I don't understand the line  "video counts are increased based on unique IP address/session requests",you mean videos count is equal to unique user count.

Comment: That depends on your application, if you are allowing users to create their accounts or not. If yes, per session base you can increase counts, if not, you must consider unique IP addresses from where you are getting the request.

Comment: @Ved.Ok means if user click we increase only one count for  video in a session.